An error due to unwanted layer in image captioning model
When i had executed model.summary(), an unwanted layer named 'NotLayer' also seem to be connected to my input layer which is giving me an error.
I even tried to access it but i can't using layers[]
please help and guide me to debug it
Here is the picture of the model summary
I tried using stack overflow and chatgpt where similar problem was addressed as custom layer but I haven't used any
I even executed an another code from a vlog to figure out about the 'NotLayer' in the model but I found it in its summary again
How can i remove it ?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
